# Using Qiskit State Tomography on Subsystems

Tags: qiskit, programming, state-tomography

I have a version of the following circuit set up.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circuit=QuantumCircuit(2)
initial_state0=[1/np.sqrt(2),1/np.sqrt(2)]     
circuit.initialize(initial_state0, 0)
initial_state1=[1, 0]
circuit.initialize(initial_state1,1)
circuit.cx(0,1)
```

I have seen that I can use StateTomography by coding the following

```
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography   
from qiskit.providers.aer import Aer
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

# QST Experiment
qstexp1 = StateTomography(circuit)
qstdata1 = qstexp1.run(backend, seed_simulation=1000).block_for_results()

# Print results
for result in qstdata1.analysis_results():
    print(result)
```

By using the coding above I am able to see how this tomography can be used to approximate the state of the entire system with fidelity being a comparison to the state of the circuit, **but my goal** is to use Quantum State Tomography (QST) on only $q_1$ and  use the fidelity to compare this to $q_0$.

I have seen in the [tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/experiments/tutorials/state_tomography.html) on Qiskit that I can run the tomography on parallel subsystems, but I'm not sure how to extend this to my goal described above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Previous edit removed as I resolved that issue independently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial, tomography on parallel subsystems assumes that subsystems are independent. From your post, I deduce you are interested in something different, i.e., performing tomography of one state after a single circuit has been executed on several qubits. To this purpose, just modify your code using `qstexp1 = StateTomography(circuit, measurement_qubits=[1])`. In this way, you will obtain the density matrix of $q_1$. Analytically, such a matrix can be obtained as the partial trace with respect to the density matrix of whole output state -- $I/2$, in your example. Indeed, your result will be (about) $I/2$, as expected.

Comment: I thought that these ```measurement_qubits``` would be the answer to this, but I didn't know I needed to list them in []!  Thank you for your help!